# BxSlider in 2 rows of 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I am trying to achieve something with BxSlider, it's too have 2 rows of 3 items showing at the same time on top of each other. With my code it only shows one row of 3 items .

It doesn't look like there is some special documentation regarding the creation of multiple rows . Can someone help me please ?

```
    $('.products-slider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 800,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    pager: false,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 12,
    slideMargin: 10,
    adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Comment: You can simple place all 6 elements (in two or X rows) inside li element/slide holder? So, this is more related to css/html?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but you need to do a bit of tweaking. Since bxSlider recognizes "slides", you'll need to put each 2 images in its own "slide" container, like this:

```
<div id="slider1">
<div class="slide">
    <!-- insert 2 images here -->
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <!-- insert 2 images here -->
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <!-- insert 2 images here -->
</div>
```